# How to stop Django from caching dynamic templates?

Tags: python, django, caching

I am really new to Django, and I'm trying have my site display a server status as text. This text, however, is dynamic. I do not understand why, if I go in my model and change the server status function to return 'cats', I don't see 'cats' appear in my browser for like 5 minutes.

From what I have learned so far, I suspect this has to do with Django caching templates on the server side. I have tried removing .pyc files, using @never_cache, and editing settings.py to use DummyCache, and clearing browser cache, all to no avail.

Does anyone know what's going on, or what a possible fix might be? Thanks!

Comment: Probably  a stupid question, but is the function cached? Also can you show us a little bit of the code please?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have cache active in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings. Also check the link below:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache

Answer (score 0):

After changing your code, make sure you are restarting your server e.g. apache or fastcgi.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option. My hosting, Bluehost, is shared hosting and so we aren't allowed to restart apache/fastcgi. Do I have any options beyond that?

Comment: [Touching the fastcgi file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#restarting-the-spawned-server) might work.

Comment: I have no experience of running Django with bluehost, so can't offer any further advice if that doesn't work.